# Conjecture about a property of concave functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, convex-analysis

Trying to prove a proposition in my paper, which can potentially use a conjecture about convex (concave) functions. This is likely to be wrong. I appreciate any thoughts on how to prove/disprove this.

**Conjecture:**
For a concave function $f(x)\geq 0$, N is a positive integer, then
$$ \frac{1}{N+1} \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{f(n)}{f(N)} $$
increases in N.

Comment: This statement is wrong for $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$. It is small disprove by counterexample.

Comment: This is not true. For special cases like $f(x) = {x}^\theta $ I can prove this conjecture. Like what I did [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485711/conjecture-about-a-property-of-convex-concave-functions)

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry. It was mistake, because I considered expression $$ \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{f(n)}{f(N)}.$$

Comment: I corrected my counterexample now: $f(x)=\sqrt{x+1}$ (in answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counterexample:

$$
f(x) = \sqrt{x+1}.
$$

$N=1:~~~$ 
$\dfrac{1}{N+1}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N}\dfrac{f(n)}{f(N)} = 
\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right) 
\approx 0.853553...;$

$N=2:~~~$ 
$\dfrac{1}{N+1}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N}\dfrac{f(n)}{f(N)} = 
\dfrac{1}{3}\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}}\right) 
\approx 0.797948...;$

$N=3:~~~$ 
$\dfrac{1}{N+1}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N}\dfrac{f(n)}{f(N)} = 
\dfrac{1}{4}\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+2}{2}\right) 
\approx 0.768283...;$

$\cdots$

We can see that (at least) first terms are decreasing.